# jquery mobile : set padding to main page Div element so that padding + width = device-width

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

i want to set a padding to the main page DIV element of the document so that 
padding + width (of the page Div element ) = Device-Width

i want to set a padding of 10px and want the page element to take up the rest of the device-width.

the problem is that even if set the padding, the page element is taking the same width ( 100% ) as device width.

i have the following thing in place -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <style>
            #page1
            {
                padding:10px;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

now, if say, the device-width is 480px 
the "page1" is taking width of 480px - 
i want to it take a width of 460px (ie excluding the padding of 20px )
in general, if device width is n then i want the page div to take a width of "n - 20"

the reason "page1" is taking same width is because the jquery-mobile css specify the width as 100% (in the ui-page css class)

i tried following to override it by doing this

```
\#page1
{
   width:auto;
}
```

but doing that causes the page to take up incorrect width - a width based on the children width;

i can't specify width in percentage in css because i dont the device-width prior and i dont have the padding in percentage - otherwise if padding is 5% then i could specify the width as 90%, since it is 10px hardcoded, i cant specify a percentage for page element.

usually, the div ( which is a block element ) with width = auto causes the div to take up space equal to its parent width excluding its padding/margins/border - but wrt "page"  (which is internally a DIV element) that doesnt seem to be case -

Any ideas on how to get this working ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be to use Modernizr to detect the max-device-width or max-width:

```
if (Modernizr.mq("screen and (max-width: 480px)")) {
  // set width of page class = 480-n
}
.. settings for other common screen widths ..
```

The main issue with this solution is that it isn't arbitrary so you would need to write a case for each device you wanted to support. Testing `window.screen.width` might be better for your purposes.